# AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'buffer'?

Tags: python, python-typing, pdoc

I have this function that simply writes a string into a stream buffer:

```py
import sys
from typing import IO

def write(s: str, stream: IO[bytes] = sys.stdout.buffer):
    stream.write(s.encode())
    stream.flush()
```

I'm using both flake8 and mypy which don't complaint while pdoc throws an attribute error:

```
[...]

    def write(s: str, stream: IO[bytes] = sys.stdout.buffer):
AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You could not use `.buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but since stdout is a `TextIO` I've rewritten the function as:

```py
def write(s: str, stream: TextIO = sys.stdout):
    stream.write(s)
    stream.flush()
```